# How to migrate history from one sonarqube server to another?

Tags: mysql, oracle, sonarqube, migration

How can I migrate the history from one sonarqube server to another in which the first is using MySQL as the database and the second one is using Oracle?

I would like to have the history of scans of the old sonarqube in the new sonarqube server along with date and in a sequential manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SonarSource has created a FLOSS migrater for just this case:

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/end-of-life-of-mysql-support/8667

You will use it to migrate your data from MySQL to Oracle and thus retain all your projects and their history.

Comment: Thankyou @G. Ann - SonarSource Team,but  it was given that the source and the destination sonarqubes must be of same version there. But in my case the old/source sonarqube is having 5.6.4 version and the new/destination sonarqube is having 6.7.4 version. Can please give a solution for this situation.

Comment: This is a different scenario than what I answered. AND the answer to your followup is to upgrade the 5.6.4 instance.